# How to check uploaded wcf service on web server

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, webserver

I have uploaded my wcf web service project on my already purchased godaddy web server. How to check if the web service is accessible on the web ?

Comment: Issue a request to its endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can just http://site/service.svc  and see a page about you have created a service blah blah.. and do http://site/service.svc?singleWsdl to see a list of available calls